# HorizontalScrollView with ListView--documentation bug?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

The documentation for HorizontalScrollView has the following:

> You should never use a
>   HorizontalScrollView with a ListView,
>   since ListView takes care of its own
>   scrolling. Most importantly, doing
>   this defeats all of the important
>   optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively
>   forces the ListView to display its
>   entire list of items to fill up the
>   infinite container supplied by
>   HorizontalScrollView.

The reasoning here seems to apply to a (vertically scrolling) ScrollView, since ListView also scrolls vertically. But ScrollView doesn't have any such caveat. Did Google put this warning in the wrong class, or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug indeed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2781

Comment: I was very much on the fence about doing this in my own app, until I ran across this question and then found the bug report. I've implemented this and have had a lot of positive things to say about the result.