# Android: ListView in HorizontalScrollView performance issues

Tags: android, performance, listview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a need for both horizontal and vertical scrolling of some data in my app. I've overridden `HorizontalScrollView` and I've allowed it to take an `Adapter` to populate its data. It behaves much like a horizontal `ListView` would behave, except I'm not doing any view recycling. Each item in my custom `HorizontalScrollView` is a `ListView` whose items are also populated with an `Adapter`. Each item in the `ListView` is a complex view.

I'm able to scroll horizontally, and vertically just fine except that it's performance is a bit chunky. The getView() method in the adapter for populating the custom `HorizontalScrollView` is only called when the `Adapter` is first set on the view. However, I noticed that getView() is constantly being called for the ListViews in the `HorizontalScrollView`. I'm wondering is this is the performance problem?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825086/horizontalscrollview-with-listview-documentation-bug) points out a supposed documentation bug pertaining to using a `ListView` inside of a `HorizontalScrollView`, but the same warning is not given in the documentation for the vertically scrolling `ScrollView` documentation.

Will I have performance issues if I put ScrollViews inside of the HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: Have you profiled the methods to see where the performance problem exactly is?

Comment: You should profile your custom code. It looks like you are forcing your ListView to relayout itself too often, thus causing the calls to getView().

Comment: @RomainGuy Do you have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Profile your code with DDMS/traceview and you'll find out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving the `ListView` a dip value for `layout_height` did the trick. Not setting a height was causing the `ListView` to keep measuring, calling getView, etc.

Comment: This had been driving me nuts! For me however a combination of setting the `layout_height` as well as overriding the `onInterceptTouchEvent` did the trick